# SQL pivot creating new columns

Tags: sql

How to transfer values to the new column, to avoid duplication of rows.

```
SELECT
    I.ID,
    I.Value (string)
FROM
    Table as I


id   |   value
----------------
1    |  Type1
1    |  Type2
2    |  Type1
2    |  Type2     
2    |  Type3         
3    |  Type1             
3    |  Type2             
3    |  Type3
```

**AIM** values presented in line 1 for a given identifier

```
id   |  value1 | value2| value3  
-------------------------------
1    |  Type1  | Type2 | null
2    |  Type1  | Type2 | Type3
3    |  Type1  | Type2 | Type3
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation after enumerating the values:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then value end) as value1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then value end) as value2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then value end) as value3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by value) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the presented solution is not universal, the ID column does not contain only 3 unique id's, but 500,000.

Comment: @Goffer . . . That doesn't matter.  This shows three values per id ragardless of the number of ids, as your question asks.